# smooth gradients in web browser

Tags: gradient, smoothing

im trying to make a smooth gradient, a simple image in photoshop/illustrator or any other software.. in some monitors/graphics card i get a really smooth image but in computers with onboard cards or bad cards i get something that looks like "artifacts" or "ditter"

how can i improve this? i mean, theres any browser filter (javascript, jquery, css3...) that i can apply, reprocess the image somehow or something? even if i keep the image quality as 100% or lossless, jpeg/png, i get the same results

thank you

Comment: Can you post an example image? You don't resize the image with HTML do you?

Comment: i dont think i can post a example because it happens with every gradient i make but you can only see in some computers, here we have more than 15 computers and i get similar results only on the bad computers..i dont resize or reprocess the images in anyway, i even tried to change the bit depth in photoshop, illustrator and fireworks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. It's entirely dependent on the color depth of the client's graphics adapter and what their monitor can handle. No matter how gorgeous a gradient looks on your $50k desktop publishing system with 48bit color depth, it'll look like crap on Joe Trailertrash's 16color EGA display hooked up to a 1940's era B&W tv